# Oracle enterperise manager start error

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, enterprise-manager

I have Oracle database 11GR2 on Windows 7.

When I want to start enterprise manager the error below is shown:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
>   Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\SHOJAIE>emctl start dbconsole
>   Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control Release 11.2.0.1.0
>   Copyright (c) 1996, 2010 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   https://SHOJAIE-PC:1158/em/console/aboutApplication
>   Starting Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control ...System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.

Answer (score 1):

a) you need a command prompt with elevated privileges (run as administrator) to do this

b) alternatively, you can start the service from Windows GUI (services.msc)

Answer (score 0):

AS mention your error shows like "**System error 5 has occurred**". It's `administrator` privilege Error.

if you are using `Oracle 11g R2` in `windows 7`, simply right click on `CMD` and run it as `administrator`.